# Low slope roof (2:12) - acceptable for metal roofing?

Tags: roof, roofing, metal-roof

I'm designing a garage for my backyard and I want to obscure my view as little as possible.  I've read that asphalt shingles aren't great on a 2:12 slope, so I'm just planning on using metal roofing.  This should be adequate right?

As for installation, I'm planning on felting the entire roof, sealing the edges where one piece meets the other with roofing tar, then screwing the whole thing down.  Is this appropriate?

I live in Alberta, so snow is a given.  Also, the garage won't be insulated or heated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the product. Some are rated down to that low a slope, and some aren't. I've seen 3:12 specified as the minimum for many, but there are some that allow 2:12. Make sure you choose one of those. As for installation, just follow the instructions. Don't try to get creative. The people who design these products are very explicit about how they are supposed to be installed. Screwing down through-fastened panels is the easy part; pay close attention to the trim.

Comment: You know, for some reason it didn't even occur to me that the product would come with instructions.